# Facebook Messenger Plugin does not render when not logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, messenger

The code only works in the website when a Facebook account already logged-in.

(1st Issue)
If there is no Facebook account logged-in before going to the website's contact page, the messenger icon (inside the website) does not appear.

(2nd Issue)
While I am in the website's contact page; then, I logged-out on my Facebook account. The chat messenger inside the chat will have an error -- "www.facebook.com refused to connect".

```js
<!-- Messenger Chat Plugin Code -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
          <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v10.0'
              });
            };
    
            (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
          </script>
    
          <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
          <div class="fb-customerchat"
            attribution="page_inbox"
            page_id="100921746716944">
          </div>
```

Comment: Does your page have Age or Country gating? "If your Page has age or country restrictions set in Page settings, the Chat Plugin will not render for users who are not logged into their Facebook account when they visit your website." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin/#login

Comment: Can you share the URL where you are trying to implement this?